# How to allocate from heap with the correct memory alignment for InterlockedIncrement function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, heap-memory, memory-alignment

This code seems to work, but have I used the InterlockedIncrement function correctly? The correct memory alignment of m_count is of my primary concern. Assume we're on a x86-64 system and compile a 64-bit application (in case that matters). By the way, for my actual purposes I can't declare m_count as a volatile long and then use InterlockedIncrement(&m_count); but it must be a pointer to data in heap.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>

class ThreadSafeCounter {
public:
    ThreadSafeCounter()
    {
        // Are those arguments for size and alignment correct?
        void* placement = _aligned_malloc( sizeof(long), sizeof(long) );
        m_count = new (placement) long(0);
    }
    ~ThreadSafeCounter()
    {
        _aligned_free( const_cast<long*>(m_count) );
    }

    void AddOne()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(m_count);
    }

    long GetCount()
    {
        return *m_count;
    }

private:
    volatile long* m_count;
};
```

Comment: Why does it have to be on the heap? Because you want to use _aligned_malloc? _aligned_malloc is a compiler extension anyway, so you might as well make use of the #pragma pack directives available on GCC AND MSVC compilers that can achieve your alignment requirements. And again the default pragma packing on GCC and MSVC already fulfill the basic alignment requirements of the interlocked operations. So you really seem to have over thought this problem.

Comment: This ThreadSafeCounter class is just a simple example. What I'm actually doing is something like a std::shared_ptr but with some extra functionality, and for that I need to have a counter located at the heap.

Comment: the counter can be on the heap, but it need not be allocated how your doing it, and if its for something like std::shared_ptr it can be inlined in the class and decorated with an alignment, cause the _align_malloc is gonna a) kill performance and b)stick you into its own lock sections which may cause problems in a lock free enviroment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The heap allocator already aligns returned addresses to the native platform word size.  4 bytes for x86, 8 bytes for x64.  You are using *long*, 32-bit on either platform for MSVC.  No need to jump through the _aligned_malloc() hoop.

Answer (score 3):

It's a platform architecture detail but you need to keep in mind that there's more to atomic operations than alignment. The platform ABIs usually make sure that primitive data type alignment by default is so that any operation (including atomics) will work. malloc() should never return you a misaligned pointer, not even if you ask for a single byte.

Although, in addition to that, specifically watch out for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing - meaning beyond the need to have alignment (usually a `sizeof(long)`) you also must make sure to host only a single atomically-accessed variable within the same cacheline.

That is particularly important if you plan to use/allow arrays of these counters.

Microsoft's compilers use `__declspec(align(value))` for instructing the compiler to guarantee specific structure alignment. As others mentioned, there seems no specific need for such a data structure / class to be heap-allocated, but I can't know if you need pimpl for something else.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do for your use case is to use intrusive reference counting via inheritance, eliminating this need.

However, if you're desperate, just check out MSVC's implementation of shared_ptr.

```
    typename aligned_storage<sizeof(_Ty),
        alignment_of<_Ty>::value>::type _Storage;
    };
    _Ty *_Getptr() const {  // get pointer
        return ((_Ty *)&_Storage);
    }
```

That C-cast is quite nasty. However, this suggests to me that this object will most definitely have the correct alignment, utilizing type traits.